# How do I create a moving average based on weekly dates, grouped by multiple columns in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, zoo, moving-average

I am reading in an extremely large dataset as a `data.table` for speed. The relevant columns are `DATE` (weekly data in year-month-day strings e.g. "2017-12-25"), `V1` (Integer), `V2` (String), `V3` (Numeric). I would like to produce `V4` which is the moving average of `V3`, for the last 3 weeks (`DATE`, `DATE`-7, and `DATE`-14) 
here is a naive attempt/solution, which is terribly inefficient:

```
dt <- fread("largefile.csv")

dt$DATE <- as.IDate(dt$DATE) //convert dates to date format

V1_list <- sort(unique(dt$V1))

V2_list <- sort(unique(dt$V2))

DATE_list <- sort(unique(dt$DATE))

for(i in 1:length(V1_list)){
for(j in 1:length(V2_list)){
for(k in 3:length(DATE_list){
dt[which(dt$V1 == V1_list[i] && dt$V2 == V2_list[j] && dt$DATE == DATE_list[k]),"V4"] 
<- mean(dt[which(dt$V1 == V1_list[i] && dt$V2 == V2_list[j] && dt$DATE %in% DATE_list[k-2:k]),"V3"])
}
}
}
```

I am avoiding using `plyr` partly due to computational constraints given the 50M rows I'm using. I have investigated options with `setkey()` and `zoo` / rolling functions but I am unable to figure out how to layer in the date component (assuming I group by `V1`, `V2` and average `V3`). Apologies for not providing sample code.

Comment: Pplease add a small subset of your data using dput(head(dt, 100))

Comment: If you are using `data.table` for speed, then I suggest to use `data.table` syntax consequently, e.g. use `dt[, DATE := as.IDate(DATE)]` instead of `dt$DATE <- as.IDate(dt$DATE)`. The former updates `dt` *by reference*, i.e., without copying the whole object.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested to append a new column which is the rolling average of `V3` over the past 3 weeks grouped by `V1` and `V2` for a `data.table` of 50 M rows.

**If the `DATE` values are without gap**, i.e., without missing weeks in all groups, one possible approach is to use the `rollmeanr()` function from the `zoo` package:

```
DT[order(DATE), V4 := zoo::rollmeanr(V3, 3L, fill = NA), by = .(V1, V2)]
DT[order(V1, V2, DATE)]
```

> ```
>           DATE V1 V2 V3 V4
>  1: 2017-12-04  1  A  1 NA
>  2: 2017-12-11  1  A  2 NA
>  3: 2017-12-18  1  A  3  2
>  4: 2017-12-25  1  A  4  3
>  5: 2017-12-04  1  B  5 NA
>  6: 2017-12-11  1  B  6 NA
>  7: 2017-12-18  1  B  7  6
>  8: 2017-12-25  1  B  8  7
>  9: 2017-12-04  2  A  9 NA
> 10: 2017-12-11  2  A 10 NA
> 11: 2017-12-18  2  A 11 10
> 12: 2017-12-25  2  A 12 11
> 13: 2017-12-04  2  B 13 NA
> 14: 2017-12-11  2  B 14 NA
> 15: 2017-12-18  2  B 15 14
> 16: 2017-12-25  2  B 16 15
> ```

Note that the `NA`s are purposefully introduced because we do not have *`DATE`-7* and *`DATE`-14* values for the first two rows within each group.

Also note that this approach does *not* require type conversion of the character dates.

#### Data

According to OP's description, the `data.table` has 4 columns: `DATE` are weekly *character* dates in standard unambiguous format `%Y-%m-%d`, `V1` is of type integer, `V2` is of type character, and `V3` is of type double (numeric). `V1` and `V2` are used for grouping.

```
library(data.table)
# create data
n_week = 4L
n_V1 = 2L
# cross join
DT <- CJ(
  DATE = as.character(rev(seq(as.Date("2017-12-25"), length.out = n_week, by = "-1 week"))),
  V1 = seq_len(n_V1),
  V2 = LETTERS[1:2]
)
DT[order(V1, V2, DATE), V3 := as.numeric(seq_len(.N))][]
```

> ```
>           DATE V1 V2 V3
>  1: 2017-12-04  1  A  1
>  2: 2017-12-04  1  B  5
>  3: 2017-12-04  2  A  9
>  4: 2017-12-04  2  B 13
>  5: 2017-12-11  1  A  2
>  6: 2017-12-11  1  B  6
>  7: 2017-12-11  2  A 10
>  8: 2017-12-11  2  B 14
>  9: 2017-12-18  1  A  3
> 10: 2017-12-18  1  B  7
> 11: 2017-12-18  2  A 11
> 12: 2017-12-18  2  B 15
> 13: 2017-12-25  1  A  4
> 14: 2017-12-25  1  B  8
> 15: 2017-12-25  2  A 12
> 16: 2017-12-25  2  B 16
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to solve your problem using two inner_joins from the dplyr package:

First I created an example data.frame (1.000.000 rows):

```
V3 <- seq(from=1, to=1000000, by =1 )
DATE <- seq(from=1, to= 7000000, by =7)
dt <- data.frame(V3, DATE)
```

Does it look correct? I dropped all unnecessary content and ignored the Date format (you can subtract Dates the same way as integers)

Next, I did two innerjoins on the DATE column but the second data.frame was containing the DATE +7 and DATE +14 so you join on the correct Dates. Finally, i select the 3 interesting columns and computed the rowMean. I took like 5 seconds on my lousy MacBook.

```
inner_join(
    inner_join(x= dt, y=mutate(dt, DATE=DATE+7), by= 'DATE'),
    y = mutate(dt, DATE= DATE+14), by= 'DATE')  %>% 
    select(V3 , V3.y, V3.x) %>% 
    rowMeans()
```

and if you want to add it to your dt remember that for the first 2 dates there is no average because no DATE-14 and DATE-7 exists.

```
dt$V4 <-   c(NA, NA, inner_join(
        inner_join(x= dt, y=mutate(dt, DATE=DATE+7), by= 'DATE'),
        y = mutate(dt, DATE= DATE+14), by= 'DATE')  %>% 
        select(V3 , V3.y, V3.x) %>% 
        rowMeans())
```

Comment: It seems that you are skipping OP's requirement to group by `V1` and `V2`.

Comment: As far as I understand the question V1 and V2 are unrelated variables and therefore V4 can just be added to the original df

Comment: Please, reread the title which says *... grouped by multiple columns*. Also, the OP writes *(assuming I group by V1, V2 and average V3)*. And, BTW, if the 50 M rows do not contain any groups then `DATE` must be spanning 1 M years which is rather unlikely to get weekly data from.